Eureka Client Server Connection interface
All the Dependancies i have declared safely , but still not getting any instance on eureka server
eureka:
instance:
prefer-ip-address: true
client:
fetch-registry: true
register-with-eureka: true
service-url:
default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
i have created client configuration from service to redirect to server  but didn't get any instance on eureka server, but my application is running.

please post your application  config  ,
